# Video Embed Playback Domain Restrictions via Azure Media Services Streaming

Tags: azure-media-services

Azure Media Services seems to have several ways to add Digital Rights Management (DRM) to videos.  For my purposes, that seems a bit heavy handed, complex and possibly expensive.

Can I simply restrict which domains a given video can be embedded/played on? If so, what terminology should I be using to locate the documentation for this feature?

For example, Vimeo.com has a feature that allows me to select to embed a video only on sites I choose:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain-specific playback restriction is not currently supported on Azure Media Services.

The best alternative at this time would require setting up token authentication with a DRM policy and limiting authorized clients to those requesting from your desired domains.